# Modify value on XML file on Unix

Tags: unix, xml

i need to do something with Xml file on Unix. In particular in 1 path i have different xml files. I need to cut the first 10 digits for value tradeId tag and then paste it to issue tags

```
<issuer issuerIdScheme="http://www.remove-234.org">549300ADFPIVCPUAAAA</issuer>

<tradeId tradeIdScheme="http://www.remove-234.org">1234567890ABCDEFGHILMN</tradeId>
```

So,i need to have this result:

```
<issuer issuerIdScheme="http://www.remove-234.org">1234567890</issuer>
```

and

```
<tradeId tradeIdScheme="http://www.remove-234.org">ABCDEFGHILMN</tradeId>
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: You would need to post the XML fragment you want to manipulate, then I can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While manipulating XML on the text level has its problems, this might be good enough: Assuming we have an XML file of

```
<something>
    <issuer issuerIdScheme="http://www.remove-234.org">549300ADFPIVCPUAAAA</issuer>
    <tradeId tradeIdScheme="http://www.remove-234.org">1234567890ABCDEFGHILMN</tradeId>
</somtehing>
```

then running this through

```
grep -v '<issuer issuerIdScheme' | sed 's/<tradeId tradeIdScheme="http:\/\/www.remove-234.org">\(..........\)\([^<]*\)<\/tradeId>/<issuer issuerIdScheme="http:\/\/www.remove-234.org">\1<\/issuer>\n\t<tradeId tradeIdScheme="http:\/\/www.remove-234.org">\2<\/tradeId>/'
```

will create an output of

```
<something>
    <issuer issuerIdScheme="http://www.remove-234.org">1234567890</issuer>
    <tradeId tradeIdScheme="http://www.remove-234.org">ABCDEFGHILMN</tradeId>
</somtehing>
```

**EDIT**

For a script doing this with all XML files in a folder, try

```
#!/bin/bash

FOLDER="/home/cg/root"

for X in "$FOLDER"/*.xml; do
  test -f "$X" || continue
  mv "$X" "$X.ori" || continue
  cat "$X.ori" | grep -v '<issuer issuerIdScheme' | sed 's/<tradeId tradeIdScheme="http:\/\/www.remove-234.org">\(..........\)\([^<]*\)<\/tradeId>/<issuer issuerIdScheme="http:\/\/www.remove-234.org">\1<\/issuer>\n\t<tradeId tradeIdScheme="http:\/\/www.remove-234.org">\2<\/tradeId>/' > "$X"
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eugen!! Great work! Last things, If i want to create a script can i do this:  

#!/bin/bash
file="/home/cg/root/*.xml"   

   if [ -f "$file" ] 

   then

 ***your code***


   fi



So in this way i can modify all file in the path Correct

Comment: See my edit for a script.

Comment: Thank you very much Eugen! I wish you good day! Thanks for help!